# Laravel - Query builder get relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my project I have a Polymorphic relation. This relation is as followes:

```
Plugins
    id - integer
    composer_package - string

Themes
    id - integer
    composer_package - string

Products
    id - integer
    name - text
    ...
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

When I need to display all the products that are a Theme I do the following:

`$themes = DB::table('products')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('productable_type', Theme::class)->get();`

The code above provides me with a list of all the products where the `productable_type` field is filled with `App/Theme`, I display them with a foreach loop like this `@foreach($themes as $theme)`. Now my problem is.
I need to get the `composer_package` from the themes table that belongs to that product. So say for instance. I get a product from the products table where the `productable_id` is 3. I want the value of the `composer_package` field in the themes table where the ID is 3. When I do `{{ $theme->products->composer_package }}` or `{{ $theme->composer_package }}` It gives me the error `Undefined property` What is causing this?

This is my product model

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}


public function order_items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orderitems::class);
}
```

And this is my theme model

```
public function webshops()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Webshop::class);
}


public function products()
{
   return $this->morphMany(Product::class, 'productable');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using the `DB` facade to pull data instead of the actual models?

One issue your are having is that your polymorphic relationship is stored in the commentable_id / commentable_type field, while your function name is product. Laravel does some of its magic just by naming alone, so let's make sure the column names and polymorphic function names match up in the product model:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

After that, try something like this in the controller:

```
$themeProducts = Product::where('commentable_type', Theme::class)->get();
```

And this in the view

```
@foreach ($themeProducts as $themeProduct)
    {{ $themeProduct->commentable->composer_package }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table has "commentable", but your model is looking for "productable". You're also missing a method.

in your **product** model add:

```
public function commentable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

in your **theme** model modify the products() method to:

```
public function products(){
   return $this->morphMany(Product::class, 'commentable');
}
```

You could also update your `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` columns in your table to `productable_type` and `productable_id`, in which case you need to rename `commentable()` in the code for the product model above to `productable()`, and `'commentable'` to `'productable'` in the code for the theme model above.

(Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

Create relations with the model as mentioned in above answers, then you can retrieve relations using with helper.
E.g.:
Product::where('commentable_type', Theme::class)->with('commentable')->get();

and then can directly use as mentioned above.
e.g.: $themeProduct->commentable